# Banner rotator with bg color change and fade javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, fadein, rotator

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgs = new Array("images/banner2.jpg", "images/banner3.jpg", "images/banner4.jpg");
    var alt = new Array();
    var bgcolor = new Array("#202020", "#00040F", "#202020");
    var currentAd = 0;
    var imgCt = 3;

    function cycle() {
        if (currentAd == imgCt) {
            currentAd = 0;
        }
        var div = document.getElementById('banner_bar');
        div.style.backgroundColor = bgcolor[currentAd]
        var banner = document.getElementById('adBanner');
        banner.src = imgs[currentAd]
        banner.alt = alt[currentAd]
        currentAd++;
    }
    window.setInterval("cycle()", 8000);        
</script>   
<div id="banner_bar">
    <img class="banner" src="images/banner4.png" id="adBanner"> 
</div>
```

The background and image change work great but I cant get the fade to work.  It either breaks the rotator or it just does nothing.  Any thoughts on how I could do this with rewriting the rotation code?

EDIT: I dunno if I am even on the right track here but if anyone could nudge me in the right direction I would appreciate it

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imgs = new Array("images/banner2.jpg","images/banner3.jpg","images/banner4.jpg");
        var alt = new Array();
        var bgcolor = new Array("#FFF","#00040F","#000");
        var currentAd = 0;
        var imgCt = 3;
        function cycle() {
            if (currentAd == imgCt) {
                currentAd = 0;
            }
            $("#banner_bar").fadeOut(3000, function () {
                var div = document.getElementById('banner_bar');
                div.style.backgroundColor=bgcolor[currentAd]
                var banner = document.getElementById('adBanner');
                banner.src=imgs[currentAd]
                banner.alt=alt[currentAd]
                currentAd++;
            ) };
        }
        window.setInterval("cycle()",5000);
    </script>
    <div id="banner_bar">
        <img class="banner" src="images/banner4.jpg" id="adBanner">
    </div>
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted has anything to do with fading.

Comment: What part of this snippet do you think is executing a fade?

Comment: I tried adding:
        
$("#banner_bar").fadeIn(3000);

After banner.alt = alt[currentAd]

but now it simply gets to the second banner and stops no fading.
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is curious about this.  I wound up using http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ in the end.  It has been suggested here before.  I achieved the background color change by using a callback to my own function using the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            timeout: 5000,
             speed:   500,
            before: midBG,
            after: finalBG
        });
    });
    var fbgcolor = new Array("#313131","#000","#00040F","#FFF");
    var fcurrentAd = 0;
    var fimgCt = 4;
    function finalBG() { 
        if (fcurrentAd == fimgCt) {
                fcurrentAd = 0;
        }
        var fdiv = document.getElementById('banner_bar');
        fdiv.style.backgroundColor=fbgcolor[fcurrentAd]
        fcurrentAd++; 
    } 
    var mbgcolor = new Array("#989898","#191919","#000208","#808287");
    var mcurrentAd = 0;
    var mimgCt = 4;
    function midBG() { 
        if (mcurrentAd == mimgCt) {
                mcurrentAd = 0;
        }
        var mdiv = document.getElementById('banner_bar');
        mdiv.style.backgroundColor=mbgcolor[mcurrentAd]
        mcurrentAd++; 
    } 
</script>
```

It maybe a bit crude but it does work.  I will keep posting here as if I make any changes or improvements!  Thanks for you advice guys.

~Matt

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by Pointy, there are no changes made via any fading.

Comment: Oh sorry.  I took out the fade part cause it wasn't doing anything. I tried an inline onload event to fade that someone suggested on another question here but that didn't work.  I assume because the image was already loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to fade w/o using jQuery you could use CSS and assign fading properties with alpha transparency, similar to what has been done here - http://tech.pro/tutorial/725/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation.

Although I'm typically already using jQuery on my projects so I use .fade(); because I am lazy.

Comment: I looked at the article you mentioned.  Im curious about the Jquery option though.  I know nothing about Jquery.  One of the critical things I am looking for on this site is consistency across browsers.  Will that be achievable with JQuery?

Comment: @ Matthew Brown, tell me EXACTLY what you are trying to do with the above code, and I will help push you in the right direction. You don't want to start mixing dom manipulation with jquery like you are above. eg var div = document.getElementById('banner_bar'); could just be var div = $('#banner_bar');

Comment: What I am trying to get is a smooth transition between the banners (and back ground colors if possible).  Right now its BOOM every 5 seconds a new banner and BG color.  I would like it to be not so abrupt if that make sense.  I'm really not good with Javascript sorry.  I am trying but I thought in the example I did above it would fade out the current banner_bar div and then put the new one up.  I was wrong lol.